# Difference in const-ness between gcc and clang

Tags: c, gcc, struct, clang, constants

What is the reasoning behind the different error reports between gcc(assignment to read-only) and clang (no error) when compiling the same code?

Consider the following C snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct ex {
    const int x;
    int y;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct ex a;
    const struct ex b = {.x = 44, .y = 66};

    a = b;

    printf("%d, %d\n", a.x, a.y);
    printf("%d, %d\n", b.x, b.y);

    return 0;
}
```

## gcc

#### --version

```
gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.2.0
```

#### gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 test.c

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:11:7: error: assignment of read-only variable 'a'
     a = b;
       ^
```

## clang

#### --version

```
clang version 3.9.1 (branches/release_39)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
```

#### clang -Weverything -std=c99 test.c

```
<no errors>
```

Comment: This is a clang bug. `a` is not a modifiable lvalue, therefore it's a constraint violation to use it on the left-hand side of the assignment operator.

Comment: @M.M Oh I see, so one single const renders the whole struct to be an unmodifiable lvalue. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the dup.

Comment: The appropriate Clang bug is [Bug 31796](https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=31796).

Comment: @baeda no problem, it took me a few minutes to get the right terms for the search even though i knew the dup was there somewhere